# How can I initialize this std::variant data member which has two similar alternatives?

Tags: c++, initialization, variant, std-variant

The following code does not compile. Why is this restriction, and how can I bypass it? If I replace the variant declaration, it compiles.

```cpp
struct PPP
{
    int xxx;
    PPP() : x(xxx) {} // error: No matching constructor for initialization of 'std::variant<Inner1, Inner2>'

    struct Inner1
    {
        Inner1(int &x )  : c(x) {}
        int &c;
    };
    struct Inner2
    {
        Inner2(int &x )  : c(x) {}
        int &c;
    };
    struct Inner3 {};

    std::variant<Inner1, Inner2> x;
    // std::variant<Inner1, Inner3> x; // This will cause the code to compile
};
```

Answer (score 4):

The `xxx` member is an `int`.

`Inner1` and `Inner2` are both constructable from (a reference to) an `int`, so `x(xxx)` is ambiguous for `std::variant<Inner1, Inner2>` as the compiler doesn't know which type you want to construct inside the `std::variant`.

When you use `std::variant<Inner1, Inner3>` instead, there is no ambiguity since `Inner3` can't be constructed from an `int`.

---

**UPDATE**: As [Raymond mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77318898/#comment136308703_77318965) in a comment, in this case you can use one of the `std::in_place_type_t` or `std::in_place_index_t` constructors of `std::variant` to tell the compiler which inner type you want to create from the `int`.

Comment: Note that `std::variant<Inner1, Inner2>` is perfectly legal. But you have to give the constructor some help. `x(std::in_place_type<Inner1>, xxx)` or `x(std::in_place_type<Inner2>, xxx)`, depending on which variant you want to initialize.

Comment: A simpler alternative is `x(Inner1{xxx})`. Note that this alternative creates a temporary `Inner1` object that is moved into the variant. That's fine for this particular `Inner1`, but that might cause a problem for more complicated `Inner1` implementations.